# Insertion sort worst case running time

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort

Why in the worst case running time complexty of insertion sort is it n(n-1)/2 ~ n^2? highlighting the division by 2?

Answer (score 3):

1. The run time is not `n(n-1)/2`, each step requires more then 1
   machine OP (in all machine I am aware of). This is why we usually
   use [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and "ignoring" constants in algorithms
   analysis - we want to make our analysis generic and platform
   independent.
2. Insertion sort is analyzed as `n(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)` because it is
   [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). The first iteration requires 1
   step, the second 2 steps,.. the n'th requires n steps, so we get `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n-1)/2` from sum of arithmetic progression.

Comment: I understand the arithmetic progression part, but it's not clear to me where the division by 2 fits in?

Comment: @user1475421 the first iteration iteration is 1 step, the 2nd is 2 steps, the 3rs is 3 steps, ... the nth is n steps, giving you total of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` steps, which sums to `n(n-1)/2`. Are you asking why does `1 + 2 + ... + n` sums to `n(n-1)/2` ?

Comment: I understand n(n-1) part but can't understand where the /2 part fits in?

Comment: @user1475421: This is simple math. have a look at: [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), it gives a close formula how to calculate the sum of the series `1 + 2 + ... +n`

Answer (score 0):

*Introduction to algorithms* gives the details of insertion sort in chapter 2.1, which discuss the whole process of insertion sort.

The worst case is caused by the switch of subarray in reversed order.

Comment: So, I've taken the time to read the chapter you've suggested.. I've even go so far as to purchase it. Definitely worth the money. Not to put a negative on it that chapter doesn't make it clear as to why the arithmetic progression is divided by 2?

Comment: It's just a simple result of the sum of arithmetic progression which is famous when Gauss solved it as a kid.

Comment: We can deduce the expression like this: sum the first and the last as a pair, then sume the second and the last but one as a pair,etc.  It is clearly that all the sum of pair equal. Define the sum as s1. So, in order to get the original sum, we can repeat n times s1 and divided by 2, because we repeat the original sum one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been closed forever but I wanted to add this for anyone else trying to brush up on the mathematics behind the insertion sort worst case scenario. I found a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DMMhE9ca9Q) that explained the n(n-1) / 2 formula this way:

To evaluate the summation of:

[image]

You first drop it into series notation (call it s):

```
s = 1  + 2 + 3 + ... n-3+n-2+n-1
```

Then show it in reverse:

```
s = n-1+n-2+n-3+ ...  3 + 2 + 1
```

Add s to s together by adding each pair and you get: `n+n+n+....n+n+n`

Or in other words `2s = n(n-1)` because you have n, n-1 times and it took you two of those sets to get it.

So then you just need to solve the inequality `2s = n(n-1)` which comes to `s = n(n-1) / 2`.